# Subclass of UIViewController is released immediately

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, subclass

Subclassing **UIViewController** I have **UIView** within NIB file then add "**Object**" with Custom Class named **CustomViewController**, this class have **view** property connected to the UIView from NIB file and other IBOutlet UIImageView connected within Interface Builder.

My question if why this class is loaded from NIB (initWithNibName is called) and is released immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything loaded in a nib is autoreleased.  If you don't explicitly retain it, or connect it to an IBOutlet property with retain stated in the property definition, it will go away.  (And usually make you unhappy.)

Comment: I expect that view property from UIViewController is retain, isn't it ?

Comment: And my point is that I have (aside from view) @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView someProperty, connected to UIImageView from NIB. This is why I expect it shouldn't be released but it is.

Comment: The `filesOwner` already exists in your running code and (hopefully) is retained already.  It doesn't really get loaded, it does the loading (or more technically it's present when loading).  If you drag ANYTHING, including a UIViewController, onto the nib palette, it needs to be retained.  You need an outlet running from File's Owner to any top level object in the nib file.  If one of those objects is a view controller, you need an outlet to **it**.